# Python-How to set time limit for The integer linear programming(ILP) function in CVXOPT

Tags: python-2.7, linear-programming, glpk

How to set time limit for The integer linear programming(ILP) function in CVXOPT?
suppose this is my solver:

```
status,solution = glpk.ilp(W, G.T, h,B=set(range(len(W))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
from cvxopt import solvers
solvers.options['glpk'] = {'tm_lim' : 1000}  # time-limit of 1s (glpk expects [ms])
status,solution = glpk.ilp(W, G.T, h,B=set(range(len(W))))
```

Passing solver-options (within cvxopt) is described in the docs [here](http://cvxopt.org/userguide/coneprog.html#algorithm-parameters).

The available options of glpk are described in it's manual [here](http://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~elias/glpk.pdf)

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments, `tm_lim` is the variable to set, not `tm lim`!

Comment: @Panda You are right! Sorry. Copy-paste from pdf's kills underscores for me :-)

Comment: but for me it didn't work :) but below code worked:           glpk.options['tm_lim'] =OPT_TIME

Comment: That's because you use some other importing-style.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from Sascha's answer didn't work for me, which might be due to import styles. However, you can also just pass an `options` dictionary in the function call, i.e.

```
glpk.ilp(W, G.T, h,B=set(range(len(W))), options={'tm_lim': 1000})
```